# Read GloVe pre-trained embeddings into R, as a matrix

Tags: r, nlp, word-embedding, text2vec, glove

Working in R. I know the pre-trained GloVe embeddings (e.g., "glove.6B.50d.txt") can be found here: https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/. However, I've had zero luck reading this text file into R so that the product is the word embedding matrix of words by vectors. Has anyone successfully done this, either pulling from a saved .txt file or from the site itself, and if so how was that text converted to a matrix in R?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of this file so we see its structure ? You may get more direct answers asking your question on their github https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe

Comment: the 0.418 0.24968 -0.41242 0.1217 0.34527 -0.044457 -0.49688 -0.17862 -0.00066023 -0.6566 0.27843 -0.14767 -0.55677 0.14658 -0.0095095 0.011658 0.10204 -0.12792 -0.8443 -0.12181 -0.016801 -0.33279 -0.1552 -0.23131 -0.19181 -1.8823 -0.76746 0.099051 -0.42125 -0.19526 4.0071 -0.18594 -0.52287 -0.31681 0.00059213 0.0074449 0.17778 -0.15897 0.012041 -0.054223 -0.29871 -0.15749 -0.34758 -0.045637 -0.44251 0.18785 0.0027849 -0.18411 -0.11514 -0.78581
, 0.013441 0.23682 -0.16899 0.40951 0.63812 0.47709 -0.42852 -0.55641 -0.364 -0.23938 [and so on]

Comment: and that example "the" and "," are the word phrases. There was a limit on characters so I indicated [and so on] to imply the numbers go on. Thanks for suggestion on GitHub too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text file is already in a tabular form, just use `read.csv("path/to/glove.6B.50d.txt", sep = " ")` - note that the field/cell separator, in this case, is a space, not a comma.